# Why is it allowed to create more than one QCoreApplication objects?

Tags: c++, qt

Looking at the following code:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  qDebug() << QCoreApplication::instance(); // prints QCoreApplication(0x7ffd39656150)
  QCoreApplication app2(argc, argv);
  qDebug() << QCoreApplication::instance(); // prints QCoreApplication(0x7ffd39656160)

  return 0;
}
```

It looks like that it's possible to create more than one QCoreApplication objects, but that should be a singleton. What does happen to the first created QCoreApplication object? Is it destroyed or will be there two event loops when exec is called for two objects?

Comment: You're constructing the singleton twice. What did you expect? You're not supposed to do that. A singleton doesn't imply a class that acts as a handle to an underlying instance. `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC` implements that.

Comment: Run your test again. Create your two instances of `QCoreApplication` before you run the two qDebug statements and you'll see that the memory addresses are the same. This implies that singleton instance is replaced (but not deleted) when you create the second instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's illegal. You're probably running against a release build of Qt, with asserts disabled.

https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp.html#742 makes it very clear that you cannot have two QCoreApplication alive at the same time:

```
void QCoreApplicationPrivate::init()
{
    Q_Q(QCoreApplication);

    initLocale();

    Q_ASSERT_X(!QCoreApplication::self, "QCoreApplication", "there should be only one application object");
    QCoreApplication::self = q;

    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed. It's not always the compiler's job to inform you of your mistakes. You erred by assuming that just because some code compiles, it's somehow on the compiler if the code is wrong.